# In Java, can I make a constructor for non-extended instances?

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's say I have two Java classes:

```
class MyClass {
  public MyClass() {
    do_things();   
  }
}

class MyOther extends MyClass {
  public MyOther() {
    super(); // Will do_things().
  }
}
```

What if I want to do some things ONLY when the class is NOT extended? For example:

```
class MyClass {
  public MyClass() {
    do_things();
    if (!(this instanceof MyOther)) {// Ugly
      my_own_things();
    }
  }
}

class MyOther extends MyClass {
  public MyOther() {
    super(); // Will do_things() but not my_own_things.
  }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do that?

Comment: I'd argue then that you've broken the "is-a" relationship between the superclass and subclass.

Comment: It seems that your inheritance relationship isn't too strong. then why to use inheritance? . A workaround you can always override that method `my_own_thigns` in `MyOther` to empty method.. but overriding a method in constructor is not a good practice

Comment: @JimGarrison that exactly is what i think

Comment: @alfasin you can't not call `super()` ..

Comment: Well, I really do need both classes to do some things in common. There just might not be a way to test if an instance is further extended...

Comment: @nachokk my bad wording, meant not to extend...

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I can't provide using a solution using inheritance cause it seems that your relationship between child and parent is not such relationship. I would reconsider making a new design

Comment: @eje211 If you explained what you _really_ want to accomplish (i.e. give a real use case) we might be able to help.  You've narrowed the problem down to what _you_ believe is the right approach, when it most surely is not.

Comment: @JimGarrison The real use case is much more complicated. But I've come to that conclusion: I'm putting things in the constructor that should not be there. The actual use case would lead to a completely different discussion. I think that the actual conclusion is: "It's not possible and it's not possible for a good reason."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the super-class has to know about its sub-classes before they exist, then you're choosing circular dependencies, which in my view, unless you really know what you're doing, is almost always bad design. In order to fix a problem *anywhere*, you have to fix *every* problem *everywhere*, or nothing in the dependency-chain will function.

This also alludes to the problem of calling interface functions directly in the constructor, which is A Bad Thing, because once that function is overridden, the super-version will never be called again.

Although I have no idea what you're actually trying to achieve here, this might be a better design for you:

```
class MyClass {
  public MyClass() {
    do_thingsMC();   
  }
  public void do_things()  {
     do_thingsMC();
  }
  protected void do_thingsMC()  {
     //Do super-things only
  }
}

class MyOther extends MyClass {
  public MyOther() {
     super();
     do_thingsMO();
  }
  public void do_things()  {
     super.do_things();
     do_thingsMO();
  }
  protected void do_thingsMO()  {
     //Do sub-things only
  }
}
```

Now the super-things can always be done when needed (by calling `do_thingsMC()`), as can sub-things (with `do_thingsMO()`), and publically, users of your code can be assured of being able to do everything (with `do_things()`).

Comment: This is what I need. I read this a couple of hours ago and I did not get it the first time, but this is EXACTLY it! Like so many StackOverflow issues, it seems obvious now that I have the answer: when a subclass calls its parent's constructor and that parent constructor calls a method that the subclass overrides, the parent constructor will call the overridden method, not the original one. This is it; and it's much simpler than what I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems exchanging subclass with superclass would seem appropriate here. No type-check would be required this way.

If your some other functionality is being broken due to this (I assume you are at an early design phase in your project), then I'd recommend you to seriously reconsider design.

Hope this helps. Good luck.